# How to remove the bottom promo banners in Firefox for Android?

Tags: firefox-for-android, ads

When you use Firefox for Android, you periodically see banners promoting the app features such as sync, themes, etc.

[image]

Is there a way one can disable this and get rid of the distraction from surfing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try typing `about:config` in the address bar.

After you open it, search for the **browser.snippets.enabled** parameter, tap on it, then tap on the **Toggle** button.

This disables the banners from appearing in the bottom.

---

*Source: [Annoying Firefox for Android Banners - SOLVED](https://www.reddit.com/r/privacy/comments/2o0rrg/annoying_firefox_for_android_banners_solved/).*

Answer (score -2):

Deleting Firefox fixed it for me!

Deleted Firefox from my comp too, just to be sure no popups start there.

No ads from Chrome so far...